# Tippy.js event delegation - decide interactively when to show tooltip based on target

Tags: javascript, tooltip, tippyjs

Say that I want Tippy.js to work on all `div` elements whose text says "hover" (my actual desired logic is a bit more complex). Here's my failed attempt at doing so:

```js
tippy.delegate("body", {
  target: "div",
  content: "tippy",
  onShow: () => {
    //return false;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wz1drsem/

I can decide to `return false` in `onShow`, but I don't know how to access the target element in this callback. If I could, I'd check the target div's text and decide what to return.

There's the `onTrigger` callback which provides access to the DOM event (e.g. `mouseenter`), but it doesn't allow to cancel the event.

Answer (score 4):

I found the following solution:

```js
tippy.delegate("body", {
  target: "div",
  content: "tippy",
  onTrigger: (instance, event) => {
    if (event.target.textContent !== 'hover') {
      instance.disable();
    }
  },
  onUntrigger: (instance, event) => {
    instance.enable();
  },
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wz1drsem/1/